# .NET MVC3 - long POST request results in 404 on IIS7

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a problem with my form posting data in MVC3. Locally, the form POSTs successfully but on the live server when there is a lot of post data a 404 is displayed rather than the success page. The data comes from the Model that gets included in the POST, there's often a lot of data in there, some of which I am using. I've looked at changing the settings in the web.config but this hasn't helped. Here are some snippets of my code:

The View:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Bookmarked", "Bookmarklet", Model, FormMethod.Post))
{

<div class="form">
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)

 @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Url, new { @class = "hidden" })
 @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.SelectedImage, new { @class = "selected-image hidden" })

 <div class="form-left">
    <div class="row">
        <label>
            Name:
        </label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Name, new { @class = "textbox" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Name, null, new { style = "display:none" })
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <label>
            Tags:
        </label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Tags, new { @class = "textbox tb-tags", @placeholder = "", onKeyUp = "submitForm(event)" })

    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <br />
        <label>
            &nbsp;</label><a href="javascript:document.forms[0].submit()" class="button fl"><span>Bookmark</span></a>
    </div>
</div>

// The controller

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Bookmarked(BookmarkModel initialState, BookmarkModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["UserGuid"];
            HttpCookie cookie2 = Request.Cookies["Username"];
            if (cookie != null && cookie2 != null)
            {
               //do stuff with model data received from the View that the POST comes from

               da.Save(model.Name, cookie.Value);
                return View();
             }
              else
                    throw new Exception("Error saving, please try again");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
            return Bookmark(model);
        }

    }

// web.config

 <system.web>
 <httpRuntime maxUrlLength="10999" maxQueryStringLength="2097151" />
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>

<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>

<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
    <add namespace="ConsumerMVC3.App_Code"/>
  </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  <security>
     <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Thanks,
Colin

Comment: Could you show your javascript?

Comment: There's not really any javascript involved, I just use it to submit the form as I'm not using a regular submit button.

Comment: Which url is requested in the browser when you get 404?

Comment: When I look using Firebug it's a massive URL although the method states that it is POST. However the Url includes a ? and a massive querystring which I don't normally see with a POST request.

Comment: I notice that you have used the `Model` in your `Html.BeginForm` call. That's the reason why you see a massive query string => all your model properties are included in the url.

Comment: That's so I can access the model data that's returned when the view that contains the form is originally rendered. Is there another way I could access the data from the View that contains the form?

Comment: You could use hidden fields. Anyway, I doubt this is the reason for the 404 errors you are getting. What is the exact requested url? Can you see the virtual directory part in it: `http://foo.com/myappname/Bookmarklet/Bookmarked?....`?

Comment: No virtual directory, it's running in the root of a subdomain...

Comment: Alright, so when you navigate to `http://foo.com/Bookmarklet/Bookmarked?..` you get 404?

Comment: When the POST submits which a large amount of data, yes. I think you're right, it's the model being submitted that's the problem - I'm trying to rewrite it with hidden fields just now to see if that works... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't saving very much, have you considered creating a ViewModel for your view?  It can be a very summarized version of your model that is all that is required for that particular view.  It would also greatly reduce the payload going back and forth to the server.

Comment: Unfortunately because the model is used on the view quite heavily I can't do this. If the user tries to bookmark a page and isn't logged in then the Model is passed to the Login view and I need all the data again once they are logged in and return back, so cutting it back to a ViewModel doesn't help.